# GtkFileChooserNative with IFileDialog with extra widget

Tags: python, windows, gtk

According to the docs for `GtkFileChooserNative` no widget can be added.

But the underlaying `IFileDialog` impl. does support it, see [Is there an easy way to create a C# .NET file dialog with encoding dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297659/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-c-sharp-net-file-dialog-with-encoding-dialog-b)

What is the best way to add some widget like character encoding to the `IFileDialog` using Gtk, i.e. using `GtkFileChooserNative`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its entirely private so there is no supported way of doing it. You could probably do some ugly win32 things to find and modify the window directly, patch GTK itself, or you could just make a custom file chooser dialog.